# how to bcp out from sybase few columns from a table with many columns? Also can some logic be accommodated while retrieving data?

Tags: sap-ase, sqlbulkcopy, bulk, bcp

I have a huge table with 60 + columns in Sybase ASE, I want to bcp out 12 columns. I was checking syntax on [manuals](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/util/@Generic__BookTextView/10086;pt=8630) but could not find a way to mention column names.

I would also like to put some logic while retrieving data, like:

```
convt = case when A.isConvertible='0' then 'N' else 'Y'  end
```

Primarily I am looking for something like queryout available in SQL Server bcp.

I can not create objects on Sybase side. It's a source for me I can only do SELECT on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do by creating a *view* with just the columns and values you want. You can then use **bcp** to retrieve data from the view.

Since you can't create objects in the database in question, that complicates things since **bcp** only supports exporting the full object.

One way around only having select permissions on the database in question, would be to create the view in *tempdb*.  It won't be persistent between dataserver reboots, but it will allow you to **bcp** out the columns that you need.

A second work around might be to install an insance of ASE on your local system, and mount the remote tables via CIS ([Component Integration Services](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase15.cisug/html/omni_ug/omni_ug1.htm)).  At that point, you should be able to create the view you need, and perform the bcp out from your local system.

Comment: I can not create objects on Syabse side... It's a source for me I can only do SELECT on it...

Comment: That sort of information is helpful to have in your question. BCP only supports exporting the full object.

Comment: Were you able to try any of these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived by using `isql` utility in unix:

```
isql -Uuser -Sserver -Ppassword -iinputfile -ooutputfile
```

You can also format the data with `-w` and `-s` options.